# Updating Hibernate 6.1.4 to 6.1.7 broke ID generators for MariaDB

Tags: java, hibernate, mariadb

After updating Hibernate to 6.1.7, ID generators are failing, trying to DROP SEQUENCE, which is illegal in MariaDB (and probably MySQL too). This was working in 6.1.4. Tried every GenerationType.

Using: hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create

Does anyone know what changed that caused this?
Is there a property that can return it to the previous behavior, which was automatically using TABLE when SEQUENCE was selected?

I can see in the DB, using dbVisualizer, that it is actually creating SEQUENCEs.  Not sure how that is even possible since MariaDB does not support that.

Version Bump:

Hibernate: 6.1.4 -> 6.1.7

javax.persistence 3.0.0 -> 3.1.0

mariadb java client: 3.0.9

MariaDB: 10.10

Exception:

> 11:35:55.833 WARN  jdbc.message.server.ErrorPacket [main] at (org.mariadb.jdbc.util.log.Slf4JLogger:100) - Error: 4091-42S02: Unknown SEQUENCE: 'appsec.sec_users_seq'
> 11:35:55.834 WARN  tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl [main] at (org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl:27) - GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "drop sequence sec_users_seq" via JDBC Statement
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop sequence sec_users_seq" via JDBC Statement
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:419)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:403)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:286)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:178)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:149)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:117)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:242)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143)
> at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:140)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:336)
> at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415)
> at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.buildSessionFactory(MetadataImpl.java:186)
> at security.domain.SecHibernateController.initialize(SecHibernateController.java:194)
> at security.domain.SecHibernateController.(SecHibernateController.java:49)
> at security.domain.SecHibernateController.(SecHibernateController.java:43)
> at security.test.TestApp.(TestApp.java:67)
> at security.test.TestApp.main(TestApp.java:58)
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=979) Unknown SEQUENCE: 'appsec.sec_users_seq'
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:282)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:370)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.message.ClientMessage.readPacket(ClientMessage.java:137)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readPacket(StandardClient.java:840)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readResults(StandardClient.java:779)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readResponse(StandardClient.java:698)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.execute(StandardClient.java:641)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.Statement.executeInternal(Statement.java:935)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.Statement.execute(Statement.java:1061)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.Statement.execute(Statement.java:452)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
> ... 18 more

Code:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "sec_users" )
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( generator = "sec_user_seq_gen", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE )
    @SequenceGenerator( name = "sec_user_seq_gen", sequenceName = "sec_users_seq", initialValue = 101, allocationSize = 5 )
    @Column( name = "id" )
    private Long id;

}
```

Update: Removing the @SequenceGenerator seems to restore the old behavior. I still think this is a bug unless it was an intentional change.

Update: This is how I got it to work. Any deviation from this fails.

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "customer" )
public class Customer extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( generator = "customer_seq", strategy = GenerationType.TABLE )
    @Column( name = "id" )
    private Long id;

    // getter/setters

}
```

Comment: MariaDB does [support sequences](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-sequence/) for a while now (10.3+). [DROP SEQUENCE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/drop-sequence/) is allowed (MariaDB, not MySQL). The drop error is the sequence not found. Could it be the previous didn't support it and the upgrade is trying to remove it before recreating it?

Comment: Looking in the DB using dbVis the sequences were actually being produced after the upgrade, not before, and I'm on 10.10.2. Anyway, I removed SequenceGenerator and its working, so that annotation is where the problem lies.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm facing a similar error in ID generation using sequence
`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'next_val' in 'field list'
Query is: select next_val as id_val from job_seq for update`

Comment: No, we just ignore the error. Its a bug in Hibernate.